# Calling "cross" function in r generates error

Tags: r, purrr

When I call the cross function in r, it returns an error:

```
library(purrr)
cross(c(1,2,3), c(4,5,6))
```

Error: The filter function must return a single logical 'TRUE' or 'FALSE', not NULL

Any idea what's going on? This is a two-line program using code I've seen elsewhere, so I'm mystified about why it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

The second argument to `cross` is `.filter`. You want to pass values as list in `cross`.

```
library(purrr)
cross(list(c(1,2,3), c(4,5,6)))
```

Or may be use `crossing`/`cross2` ?

```
tidyr::crossing(a = c(1,2,3), b = c(4,5,6))
cross2(c(1,2,3), c(4,5,6))
```